# Windows 10 display in light color

Tags: windows-10, display

[Windows 10 display in light color, unable to read text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hf6p.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong with the screenshot, so probably you have too high contrast set on your display. Use monitor buttons to change it to 75 or 50 - these are typical "normal" values. On [this control image](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/white.php) you should be able to clearly see a checkerboard in the first row and at least faintly see it in the middle one.